# Design of a linear actuator that is only 5 mm wide

Tags: linear-motion, actuator, linear-motors

I have to design a linear actuator with a maximum movement of 3 cm back and forth and a maximum force of 5 N. The only constraint I have is that it can only be 5 mm wide. There's no real constraint regarding length and height. Ideally, I'd like to be able to coarsely control the position of the actuator.

I've though designing a linear stepper motor, but being only 5 mm wide there's not much space for the windings, which means that the current needs to be high and the losses become unmanageable.

Pneumatic actuators need valves, which are too large. Same for other kind of mechanical solution needing normal motors. And there's also thermal actuators (wax motor), but they're really slow.

Is there any other way that I could design this actuator?

EDIT: I didn't mention that I will need hundreds of these actuators working together (it's for a kinetic art sculpture), so the only element that I was considering to leave out is the power source.

Comment: Why put valves on the actuator? just have air supplied to both sides and control the pressure difference elsewhere.

Comment: An electrical actuator will need batteries or some other power supply. If you have room for that how can you not have room for valves someplace? I think we need more information, possibly with a sketch.

Comment: Does this whole device including power source need to fit inside a gap that is 5mm wide?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited the question adding more information. I like the idea of placing the valves elsewhere, but I'm afraid they will take up a lot of room (including an air compressor). However, if the valves and compressor are small enough, how does a pressure control system look like and which elements are needed?